# How to get User within a [AllowAnonymous] controller and AzureAdB2C?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I'm using msal for angular and AzureAdB2C for authentication/authorization. I would like to get the Authenticated User within a controller **if the User is logged in**.
I'm using the following code snippet which works with the `[Authorize]` attribute and the route protected: `var id = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;` However, it returns null when I add the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute to the controller. I tried adding the Bearer token to the Authorization header on my API call, but this did not help. If I add the route to the protected list, then it forces the user to login every time. Any way of doing this with latest version of msal-angular / .NET core 3.1?